# Setting the correct orientation for scrollbars in right-to-left pages

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, right-to-left

I'm working with right-to-left layouts at the moment (think Hebrew or Arabic).  In RTL, the page is generally flipped horizontally.  However, I can't figure out how to change the orientation of the scrollbars.  I would assume that the scrollbars should appear on the left side of a scrollable element, not the right side like it does in an LTR layout.

Here is an example page where the scrollbar still appears on the right:

```
<html dir="rtl">
<body>
<div style="height: 100px; overflow: auto;">
    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>This is some text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is the orientation of a scrollbar a browser locale setting, and thus is not something I should be concerned about, or is there a way to set the orientation of the scrollbar?

(I'm not interested in implementing my own JavaScript scrollbar; if it turns out this is just a limitation of browsers then I'd rather live with that than add complexity to the page.)

Comment: Just as a sidenote, I am an Arab, and most of the website I know keep the scrollbar in its default location (which is, I imagine, system-specific).

Comment: Perhaps it's worth asking your users how they feel about switching the scrollbar, do they find it more useable?

Comment: When you are in RTL layout and you are placing a menu on the right. Being an scroll bar beside it is not a good idea. And usually if we have a table on the page it will placed on the left side and it is better to see the scroll bar beside it. I think it is more sensible placing the scroll bar in the opposite.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to do this, I'm an Arab myself and I find it really annoying when the scrollbars are on the left.

Comment: Do you know of any good resources which explain what people in RTL locales expect?  That's a bigger overall problem - knowing what is desired in the first place.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know of any resources that discuss this, also, google didn't return much about it. But anyway, what I can say is that it's not good to be done 'per window'. In other words if the user is using mirroring (I'm referring to the settings of their OS), then you don't need to do anything as the user already chose what they want. But if the user is not using mirroring, it means they have the scrollbars on the right for all windows, and it gets really annoying when they have a window with scrollbars on the left. It should be left to the OS settings.

Comment: I'm not completely sure but I think the majority of Arabic speakers don't use mirroring anyway, this is esp. true for Windows XP and Vista. Well, at least none of the people I know use it.

Comment: true, the browser window belongs to the user, and the user sets the OS to a certain direction, the html should not dictate that setting, because the user who uses a browser to browse RTL sites, is the same user who browses YouTube in LTR, so it would be absolutely annoying to break his experience... chrome and firefox do it right, IE still annoys me so much I actually work around it by putting the RTL property on a div inside the body

Comment: I have a right to left site so the side menu is at the right and the scrollbar at the right is very annoying because it sits on the menu making it difficult to read what's written on the menu items.

Comment: Isn't it better that browser respects the developer decision. In some cases there is a fixed position item like sidebars on the left hand in ltr. and in the rtl direction they are on the right. Isn't it better that developer have the option for placing the scroll bar in opposite? In these cases the scroll bar doesn't have any effect on the element beside it.

Comment: @WaleedEissa, What do you think about https://rtlstyling.com/posts/rtl-styling#bidirectional-vertical-scrollbars ?

Answer (score 3):

Just do that to the body tag :

```
<body dir="rtl">
```

and it will work fine for IE only.

Firefox, Safari and Chrome is another story, you need some Javascript to get it work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to flip the side of the page scrollbars, because it is an UI element while you can control only the page content (HTML).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the dir attribute to the body tag like so:

```
<body dir="rtl">
```

The catch is that the behaviour is erratic in different browsers.  Most newer browser will flip the content from right to left as you'd expect, but only IE and Opera also move the scrollbar to the left side.

Comment: In Opera, the user can force the scrollbar to the right: opera:config#RTL%20Flips%20UI

Answer (score 0):

Just add "direction:rtl;" to your div.

```
<html dir="rtl">
<body>
<div style="height: 100px; overflow: auto;direction: rtl;">
    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>This is some text</p>
</body>
</html>
```